# JFrame resize to visible components

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have an application where I want that the user is able to choose between normal and advanced settings. Now if the user checks a JCheckBox and the advanced settings should disapper the problem starts.
My idea was to set all unnessecary swing components (JScrollPane, JLabel...) invisible and then find a method of JFrame which fits the window to the VISIBLE components.
My question is if there is such a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** You can use  `setVisible(boolean b)`, to make the component visible and invisible.

**2.** You can check that if the component is visible or not using `isVisible()`

**3.** You can then use the pack() method, **pack() method gives sets the frame size as per need**

Comment: I already knew how to make visivle and invisible ^^ I also tried it with pack() but it didnt work...   Here my code with the pack() method in it:  `if(jChkBxAdvanced.isSelected() == true){
            jScrollTargetList.setVisible(true);
            jButtNewTarget.setVisible(true);
            jLblAddedTargets.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
           jScrollTargetList.setVisible(false);
           jButtNewTarget.setVisible(false); 
           jLblAddedTargets.setVisible(false);
        }
        
        this.pack();`

Answer (score 6):

> ... and then find a method of JFrame which fits the window to the VISIBLE components. My question is if there is such a method?

Yes, there is such a method, and it is called `pack()`.

This will cascade through the layout managers of all the containers held by the top-level window, asking them to re-lay out their visible components, resizing components to their preferred sizes as based on the components and the layout manager requirements, and eventually resizes the top-level window to fit the containers and their components.

Comment: oh ok thanks. I already tried pack() but it seemed that it didn't work. Now I saw that it really resizes well but my panel is so big that it looks like there is no actual resize... however another thanks for that vivid description of the method ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap the advanced content in a panel (if possible) and remove that panel from frame using `this.remove(component)` then use `this.pack()`
and you can do the opposite on showing them, `this.add(...)` then `this.pack()` again